# itemssource only works in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm playing with this example:
(check the bottom last code `The final and working example`)
http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/responding-to-changes/

In the code he is doing the binding with `lbUsers.ItemsSource = users;` right? Im trying to do the binding in the xaml instead of code-behind:

```
<ListBox Name="lbUsers" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource = {Binding users}></ListBox>
```

But this doesnt work. Then I tried adding Datacontext but still it's not working

I read this post: [WPF ItemsSource works in code-behind but not in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292271/wpf-itemssource-works-in-code-behind-but-not-in-xaml) 
but still couldn't understand my problem

Comment: Where is _your_ `users` list coming from? Are you setting it in the code-behind of the Control/Page? Or are you using a ViewModel to bind the control's `DataContext` to? Your question loosely alludes to code-behind (where you're referring to someone else's `users` list as an example). Please could you clarify?

Comment: For what purpose do you _need_ to be setting the `ItemsSource` in a XAML binding? If you're just following the tutorial, that code would suffice. If you are looking to extend the use of the code and, let's say, have a ViewModel to bind to and then do something more with the users; that's a bit different - see @H.B.'s answer and do a bit of research on MVVM :)

Comment: Hey yeah, I know the code works, but since I want to eventually do MVVM, I'm trying to play around with binding first. As for the users list it's same as in the tutorial code (bottom of the page). All Im trying to do is do the binding in the xaml instead of code behind, so I can eventually bind it to a list in a viewModel class. I honestly been spending the whole day reading but trying but to no avail, if you can shed some light Id rly appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private ObservableCollection<User> users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
```

You can only bind to **public properties**, this is a **private field**. Read the [data binding overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), please.

Also, [failing bindings can be debugged](http://wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html).

Comment: You're right - you can only bind to public properties; but I think that you need to be sure that 1. the `List<User>` that OP is referring to _is_ private/public and that 2. the OP is setting up the `DataContext` correctly, and where from (such as `Self` or from a ViewModel etc.)

Comment: @GeoffJames: True, there are tons of other possible mistakes, i cannot cover them all, it's best for the OP to get a decent understanding of the binding system for that reason.

Comment: Absolutely loads and loads of other potential causes, definitely. I'm on your side with this one - based on the naming convention that seems to be pretty popular of naming private fields / public members - I guess only time (and OP) will tell...

Comment: @GeoffJames: That's from the original tutorial linked in the question, so if the OP did not change anything, this is one of the problems with the binding.

Comment: Oh deary me... I've just had a _proper_ look at the tut -.- My faith in humanity is running dry

Comment: wait, can you guys fill me in? I didn't change anything from tutorial, just playing around with it. So I've changed the list to public, and put  `ItemsSource="{Binding users}`, what else am I missing here?

Comment: @user1294510 If you only changed the list to public, it's now a public *field*, and it should be a *property*, so what you're literally missing is a public getter.